# LINQ: How to search 2 list ( Two list: Entity List and Array ) combined?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Suppose I am an entity of `Member` and a list of names that I do not want to include.

```
var excludeNames = new [] { "A","B","C","D"};

var members = db.Members.Except(excludeNames);
```

or

```
 var excludeNames = new[]{ "A","B","C","D"};
 var Members = db.Members.Where(m=> excludeNames.Where(xcl => xcl != m.Name));
```

None of these is working.
I also tried this:

```
 var excludeNames = new[] { "A","B","C","D"};
 var members = from m in db.Members
               from xcl in excludeNames
               where m.Name != xcl
               select m;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The last example should surely work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one can be a good solution.

```
var excludeNames = new [] { "A","B","C","D"};

var members = db.Members.Where(member => excludeNames.Any(member.Name) == false).ToList() ;

//or     
var excludeNames = new [] { "A","B","C","D"};

var members = db.Members.Where(member => !excludeNames.Any(member.Name)).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
var excludeNames = new[] { "A","B","C","D"};
var members = from m in db.Members
              where !excludeNames.Contains(m.Name)
              select m;
```

Note that even when LINQ allows you to phrase a query in multiple ways, you'll still need to account for the fact that your query needs to be translated to SQL. And the dialects of SQL that Entity Framework supports treat lists of values differently from row sets.

For instance, the query you want to build in SQL would be

```
SELECT *
FROM Members AS m
WHERE m.name NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C')
```

(An `x IN (list)` in SQL translates to `list.Contains(x)` in LINQ.)

For instance, you are not allowed to say something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Members AS m
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C') AS xcl
             WHERE m.name != xcl)
```

Nor

```
SELECT *
FROM Members AS m,
     ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C') AS xcl
WHERE m.name != xcl
```

These queries are simply not allowed. And although Entity Framework can be quite smart when translating your LINQ query to SQL, it does have its limitations.